# Find percentage of rows that meet a condition without rounding

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count, sum

I'm trying to find the percentage of rows that meet a specific condition. My query is close but the answer is always rounded to the nearest whole number.

For instance this query below is returning 6 but it should return 6.25. Meaning 6.25% of the rows meet that condition. How would I do this?

```
select sum(case when name like 'H%' then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / count(*)
from category
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a decimal point:

```
select sum(case when name like 'H%' then 1.0 else 0 end) * 100 / count(*)
from category;
```

Postgres does integer division.

You can also express this using `avg()`:

```
select avg(case when name like 'H%' then 100.0 else 0 end)
from category;
```

The decimal point is not needed.  Although Postgres does integer division of integers, it calculates average of integers using decimal points.

And this can be phrase more simply (assuming that `name` is not `NULL`):

```
select avg( (name like 'H%')::int ) * 100
from category;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon and the rest who answered. I appreciate the help! That worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need a decimal value, otherwise, since both the numerator and denominator are integers, Postgres does integer division.

But here, I would just use `avg()` - for which you don't need an integer value:

```
select avg(case when name like 'H%' then 1 else 0 end) * 100
from category
```

Answer (score 0):

You're performing [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers), and thus omitting everything right of the decimal point. If you use a floating-point literal `100.0`, you should be OK:

```sql
select sum(case when name like 'H%' then 1 else 0 end) * 100.0 / count(*)
from category
```